# Getting a list of users for an Active Directory group with PHP

Tags: php, ldap

I have created a PHP script to query an LDAP server (running Microsoft Active Directory) and retrieve a list of Groups from a specific OU.  This all works OK.  However, I now need to pull out the list of Users for each Group.  The attributes returned from AD, don't appear to include this, and I can't find a way to pull them out.

I have created a work around which will pull every User from a specific OU and check it's list of Groups against the one I am looking at, but this is very inefficient as I am generally pulling 100+ Groups.

Another concern, is that each Group could potentially have Users from 70+ different domains, which would be impossible to search each time.

So, basically, I need to be able to pull the list of Users directly from the Groups.  Does anyone know a way I can achieve this with PHP?

Comment: When you say groups, are you looking for the `Member Of` attribute?

Comment: The 'Member Of' attribute applies to the User - I want the 'Members' attribute that apples to Groups.  I want to know the Members of a Group, rather than the Groups of a Member.

Comment: @sacredzero Can't you just get the group, and run a query against the users to find everything with a `memberOf=[group]`? Not very efficient I admit.

Comment: That is what I am doing at the moment.  But with 100+ groups, this means 100+ queries to the LDAP server.  Added to that as I explained in my original post, I need to get any Users from other Domains in our Forest, and I can't keep querying every single domain over and over.

Comment: You should just be able to look at the "member" attribute. It contains the DN's of the members. Are you not seeing that attribute? Post some code if not

Comment: There is way too much code to try and work out what is going on >_<  Do I need to be authenticated to see the Member attribute?  I have been connecting anonymously, which has been giving me everything else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to bind with a valid username/password to be able to see the "members" attribute.  Threw me for a bit, as most other stuff seems to be available without authenticating.